# How do I change contents of my JavaFX application from outside of application

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on big java swing application, there was a need to embed an information window based on interactive html (with buttons, when clicked, a certain action is performed). The information window is implemented as a JavaFX application, into which, through the arguments, I pass the id of the object, information about which I want to display. Internally, the application performs the necessary logic and shows the stage with html. Everything works well, except that I can only open the window once. I know the launch method cannot be called twice, then how can I pass a new argument to the javafx application and rebuild the stage according to the new object id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to integrate a whole JavaFX application into your Swing app. Instead use a JFXPanel. Have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm